# How to stop postback in image button

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

How to avoid the post back in Image button.I tried this way but on clicking the image button my text box is not showing.

My issue is ->image button is doing a postback on each click .For avoiding that i tried to use java script as below.On click of button i want to show a **textbox** which have lot of functionalities in TextBox1_TextChanged event.But it is not working...

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" 
    OnClientClick="return ValidNum();" onClick="ImageButton1_Click" Height="52px" 
    ImageUrl="search1.png" style="margin-right: 0px" Width="126px" />


<script>

        function ValidNum() {

            return false;

        }

</script>
```

And in code behind i have

```
 Protected Sub ImageButton1_Click(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.ImageClickEventArgs) Handles ImageButton1.Click
    TextBox1.Visible = True

 End Sub
```

**EDIT**
Now i changed my code as below but-BC30456: 'return' is not a member of 'ASP.about_aspx' ERROR is showing

```
  <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" 
    OnClientClick="return ValidNum();" onClick="return showBox();" Height="52px" 
    ImageUrl="~/search1.png" style="margin-right: 0px" Width="126px" />

<script>
function showBox() {
var theControl = document.getElementById("<%=Textbox1.ClientID %>");
theControl.style.display = "";
}
```

```
<script>

        function ValidNum() {

            return false;

        }

 </script>
```

Thank You

Comment: Please explain the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Your code relies on doing a postback since you have a server side event handler for showing the textbox. The event handler is prevented from running if you don't to a postback here. If you want to avoid a postback and still manage visibility of the textbox you have to hide/show the textbox in javascript instead.

Comment: Can i use asp.net text box for this.Becoz my textbox have lot of function in it its TextBox1_TextChanged Event

Comment: Remove the following line onClick="return showBox();" Put both javascript functions into one wrapper function and call it from OnClientClick

Answer (score 0):

> theControl.style.display = "none"; // to hide
>
> theControl.style.display = "block"; // to show